# Usar o decorator Input ou declarar nos meta dados?

Tags: angular, desempenho, typescript

tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Hoje até onde eu vi existem 2 maneira de se receber uma informação em um Component do Angular.

Mas fico em dúvida no quesito "performance".

> O exemplo abaixo eu faço o import do Input do pacote "@angular/core":

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-meu',
    template: `<h1>Meu nome é {{ meuNome }}</h1>`
})
export class MeuComponent {
     @Input('nome') meuNome: string = '';
     constructor() {}
}
```

> Já no exemplo abaixo eu faço a mesma coisa, sem a necessidade de fazer o import

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-meu',
    template: `<h1>Meu nome é {{ meuNome }}</h1>`,
    inputs: ['meuNome:nome']
})
export class MeuComponent {
     meuNome: string = '';
     constructor() {}
}
```

Em ambos os casos eu conseguiria usar meu componente, passando o atributo `[nome]` e funcionaria.

Porém usando o `@Input()` eu acho mais elegante e mais fácil de se orientar no desenvolvimento sobre o que é input property ou o que é variável da minha classe.

Então vem a dúvida, o fato de usar o `@Input()` torna o código mais lento? Qual a melhor prática?

Comment: A lógica do decorator `@Input` é passar valores de um component `pai(parent)` para um component `filho(children)`.

Comment: Obrigado @Marconi! Eu entendo o uso do decorator. Á pergunta era sobre a performance mesmo. Ou seja o porque de existir as duas formas.

Comment: Hiago, ao meu ver você não utilizou o `decorator` de forma correta, ambas as formas não necessitam do `@Input`

Comment: @Marconi mas foi só um exemplo que usei na época para apresentar a minha dúvida.

Comment: Nesse exemplo eu iria usar <app-meu nome="Hiago"></app-meu>

Comment: Entendi, achei que está desenvolvendo assim rs. :D

Comment: O que você poderia fazer é rodar com as ferramentas de desenvolvedor na velocidade slow 3g e ver qual puxa o valor em menos tempo de `ms` ou `s`, acredito que pode ser que com a anotação `@Input` seja mais rápida por ir diretamente no método correto

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o [style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#!#05-12) do Angular, é aconselhado o uso de @Input. 
O uso de @Input pode facilitar em alguns casos. Segundo este post: [angular use input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33648586/what-is-the-difference-between-input-and-inputs-in-angular2-components) diz que em alguns casos pode ser que não seja reconhecido a variável com o uso do inputs dentro do componente.

Comment: Obrigado Renato, mas gostaria apenas de saber a diferença em performance. Se tinha alguma diferença ou não.